# reading and writing text file with arraylist

Tags: java, io, arraylist

I'm having problem reading text file into arraylist with multiple data types.

The file format looks like:

```
Name1 900 20

Name2 750 30

Name3 880 25

Name4 260 15
```

My list format is `name + score + age`  and I don't know how to store the data from txt into list properly. Also I want to rewrite the file after adding some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your List accepts String:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt"));
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String line=null;
while((line= reader.readLine())!=null) {
list.add(line);
}
```

however, it'd be better if you had a class with name, socre and age as properties and create an list of that class and split your text file with  white spaces .

```
class SomeClass {
private String name; 
private long score;
private int age;
//getters and setters for your properties

}
```

now your List would be:

```
   List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and after reading the line from the file, split it based on whitespace.

```
 String[] arr =line.split("\\s+");
 SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
 obj.setName(arr[0]);
 obj.setScore(Long.parseLong(arr[1]));
 obj.setAge(Integer.parseInt((arr[2]));
 list.add(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was just I needed. So String[] arr =line.split("\\s+"); this part is the spliting whitespace?

Comment: @sblck yepp, `\\s` is regex for whitespace :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class that would encapsulate name+score+age, and create an `ArrayList` of that class.